# DiagrammeR and R Markdown pdf: How to crop to the diagram?

Tags: r-markdown, diagrammer

I have made a nice flowchart in DiagrammeR. I have also plotted it into R Markdown and I am able to knitr it into a pdf. As you see in the following screenshot, the figure is not centered (even though I included `fig.align = 'center'`). But there is also a huge gap between my figure and the following text. How do I "crop" the diagram so I removes the space and center the diagram?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will find problems generally with markdown problems so you will have to modify manually from your latex code so I would recommend that you put in your yaml:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    keep_tex: true
---
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the code to the YAML with no difference?

Comment: I don't understand your question.